# Determining if 2 images are the same

Tags: c#, image

This is my program code for comparing if 2 images are the same. It basically uses the open dialog and opens 1 image at a time and puts it in 1 picture box.

I heard that `GetPixel()` method may be slow. Is there a more efficient and faster way to compare 2 if 2 images are the same?

```
Bitmap image1 = null;
Bitmap image2 = null;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //first image open
{
    OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        image1 = new Bitmap(openDialog.FileName);
        pictureBox1.Image = image1;
    }   
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //second image open
{

    OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        image2 = new Bitmap(openDialog.FileName);
        pictureBox2.Image = image2;
    }  
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //compare button
{
    if (compare(image1, image2))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Same Image.");
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Different Image.");
    }
}

private bool compare(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) 
{
    bool equals = true;
    bool flag = true;  //Inner loop isn't broken

    //Test to see if we have the same size of image
    if (bmp1.Size == bmp2.Size)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp1.Width; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp1.Height; ++y)
            {
                if (bmp1.GetPixel(x, y) != bmp2.GetPixel(x, y))
                {
                    equals = false;
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!flag)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        equals = false;
    }
    return equals;
}
```

Comment: Note that `Bitmap` inherits from `Image`, which implements `IDisposable`. This means you very much better call `Dispose()` on those objects are you are done with them (way many paths here with UI event handlers), or put them into `using` blocks.

Comment: Oh, and same goes for `OpenFileDialog`. I'll probably post an answer to show some of this.

Comment: See ImageComparer.Compare method. Has overloads to specify tolerance.
It is available since VS2102. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.imagecomparer.compare.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `LockBits` method and pointers to access the image data directly.

Example for 24 bpp images:

```
bool equals = true;
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height);
BitmapData bmpData1 = bmp1.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp1.PixelFormat);
BitmapData bmpData2 = bmp2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp2.PixelFormat);
unsafe {
  byte* ptr1 = (byte*)bmpData1.Scan0.ToPointer();
  byte* ptr2 = (byte*)bmpData2.Scan0.ToPointer();
  int width = rect.Width * 3; // for 24bpp pixel data
  for (int y = 0; equals && y < rect.Height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      if (*ptr1 != *ptr2) {
        equals = false;
        break;
      }
      ptr1++;
      ptr2++;
    }
    ptr1 += bmpData1.Stride - width;
    ptr2 += bmpData2.Stride - width;
  }
}
bmp1.UnlockBits(bmpData1);
bmp2.UnlockBits(bmpData2);
```

Comment: I assume I drag this in my `compare()` method?

Comment: @puretppc: Yes, that is correct. After checking that the images have the same size and the correct pixel format.

Comment: `BitmapData` doesn't exist for me. Also `Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe`.

Comment: @puretppc: Add `using System.Drawing.Imaging;` at the top, or use `System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData`. (If you right click on `BitmapData` both options can be done automatically under `Resolve`.) To use unsafe code you need to enable it in the project properties.

Comment: Oh ok. But now I'm getting an error saying  `'System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode' does not contain a definition for 'Read'` At the very top of the program I put `using System.Drawing.Imaging;`

Comment: @puretppc: Sorry, that should be `ReadOnly`.

Comment: +1 since it's working right now but my question is, is yours faster than the other 2 answers? I'm not a speed tester and I'm not at a pro level of programming. Please be honest though.

Comment: @puretppc: Jesse C. Slicer used my code as base for his answer so that will be just as fast, and Dan Lyons tells in his answer that it's not as fast as using pointers.

Comment: I guess yours is faster since you're using pointers right? :)

Comment: @puretppc: Well, the key is really that it accesses the data with a minimum of overhead.

Comment: @Guffa: Bit of a necropost, sorry :) If I copy an image on my HDD and compare the two, this returns a match. But if I open it in Paint, then Save As (same filetype, nothing changed, just different filename), it doesn't match. Does this only check for equality in pixels (color), or does the checking of equality also include some metainformation (or similar) that is causing my matches to fail?

Comment: @Flater: This code only checks the pixel values. When you resave an image there are several way that some pixel values can become different. If the image is compressed using JPEG, then some data is interpolated when it's uncompressed, but that data is still considered when it's resaved, so some pixels may get a color that is slightly changed from the original. An image can also be converted from one color space to another, then the pixel values will differ even if they represent the same color.

Comment: @Guffa: .tif, .png, .bmp all have the same effect when saving as the same filetype. None of them still matches its original file. I didn't consider .jpg, but I assume the results there to be even wronger due to compression. Given the other filetypes (tif png bmp), is there one that has less margin for error than others? But already thanks for your reply! :)

Comment: @Flater: All the file types that you have tested are capable of storing the image without differences (as long as .tif doesn't use the JPEG compression mode), so it looks like the program is changing the colors somehow. You could use `cmd` and run `fc /b filename1 filename2` to compare the files byte by byte to see if there is just a few values that differ, or a general shift of all pixels.

Answer (score 12):

One thing I have done in the past is to convert the images to 64-bit encoded strings and just string compare.  It won't be as fast as using pointers, naturally.  However, it can be done entirely in managed code, it doesn't require you to know bits per pixel, and it works for the Image base class.

```
byte[] image1Bytes;
byte[] image2Bytes;

using(var mstream = new MemoryStream())
{
    image1.Save(mstream, image1.RawFormat);
    image1Bytes = mstream.ToArray();
}

using(var mstream = new MemoryStream())
{
    image2.Save(mstream, image2.RawFormat);
    image2Bytes = mstream.ToArray();
}

var image164 = Convert.ToBase64String(image1Bytes);
var image264 = Convert.ToBase64String(image2Bytes);

return string.Equals(image164, image264);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked :) So my old code was about comparing BPP (bits per pixel)? I don't really know this since I got this off the another site

Comment: Note that this will also compare any meta data in the images. If they for example are identical but with different resolution settings, this will return false.

Comment: What is the purpose of converting to a base64 string?  Why not simple compare the elements of both arrays (or streams)?

Comment: It took a bit more work for me than I thought to get this method working; I read something about hashing the image data and thought Bitmap.GetHashCode() would suffice. I have several subimages I'm pulling from spritesheets and the last few spritesheets have blank subimages which I want to skip. It was either this or looping through each pixel of all subimages and checking to see if they were colorless (black with no alpha), which of course is processor-intensive. Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 9):

I'll focus on problems in `compare()`.

You're using the wrong equality comparison for the bitmap size.  You need to compare the contents of the `Size` objects, not whether they are the same reference.

A variable named `flag` should be a… *red flag*!  Not only is it vaguely named, its presence suggests that your code is ineffective.  Avoid using variables for flow control; find more active ways to get to where you need to go.

In this case, the solution is an early `return`.  As soon as you find a single difference between the two images, you're done!  You don't even need the `equals` variable.

I would also rename `compare()` for clarity, and make it `static` because it is a pure function of its two parameters.

```
private static bool Equals(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) 
{
    if (!bmp1.Size.Equals(bmp2.Size))
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < bmp1.Width; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bmp1.Height; ++y)
        {
            if (bmp1.GetPixel(x, y) != bmp2.GetPixel(x, y))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that Bitmap inherits from Image, which implements `IDisposable`. This means you very much better call `Dispose()` on those objects are you are done with them (way many paths here with UI event handlers), or put them into using blocks. Same goes for `OpenFileDialog`.

As per my comments, some `using` usage (and `try..finally` usage, incorporating [Guffa](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/7641/guffa)'s [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/39987/6172)):

```
private Bitmap image1;

private Bitmap image2;

public Form1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var openDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        if (openDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.DisposeImage1();
        this.image1 = new Bitmap(openDialog.FileName);
    }

    this.pictureBox1.Image = this.image1;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var openDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        if (openDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.DisposeImage2();
        this.image2 = new Bitmap(openDialog.FileName);
    }

    this.pictureBox2.Image = this.image2;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Compare(this.image1, this.image2) ? "Same Image." : "Different Image.");
}

private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    this.DisposeImage2();
    this.DisposeImage1();
}

private static bool Compare(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
{
    // Test to see if we have the same size of image
    if (bmp1.Size != bmp2.Size)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height);
    var bmpData1 = bmp1.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp1.PixelFormat);

    try
    {
        var bmpData2 = bmp2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp1.PixelFormat);

        try
        {
            unsafe
            {
                var ptr1 = (byte*)bmpData1.Scan0.ToPointer();
                var ptr2 = (byte*)bmpData2.Scan0.ToPointer();
                var width = 3 * rect.Width; // for 24bpp pixel data

                for (var y = 0; y < rect.Height; y++)
                {
                    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        if (*ptr1 != *ptr2)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                        ptr1++;
                        ptr2++;
                    }

                    ptr1 += bmpData1.Stride - width;
                    ptr2 += bmpData2.Stride - width;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            bmp2.UnlockBits(bmpData2);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        bmp1.UnlockBits(bmpData1);
    }

    return true;
}

private void DisposeImage1()
{
    if (this.image1 == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.pictureBox1.Image = null;
    this.image1.Dispose();
    this.image1 = null;
}

private void DisposeImage2()
{
    if (this.image2 == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.pictureBox2.Image = null;
    this.image2.Dispose();
    this.image2 = null;
}
```

Comment: `ImageLockMode` doesn't exist? Also, the unsafe I'm getting an error

Comment: You'll need to check `enable unsafe code` on the Build page of your project's options. Also, add `using System.Drawing.Imaging` to your `using` directives at the top of the file to get access to `ImageLockMode`.

Comment: in "var bmpData2 = bmp2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp1.PixelFormat)" last parameter bmp1.PixelFormat or bmp2.PixelFormat?

Comment: I got error "Bitmap region is already locked." in code "var bmpData2 = bmp2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp1.PixelFormat)"

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this SO question.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/35151067/4062881

It decreases the size of image, turns it B&W, and then uses GetPixel() to generate hash.

It is much faster, efficient, and works! It is able to find equal images with:

- different file formats (e.g. jpg, png, bmp)
- rotation (90, 180, 270) - by changing the iteration order of i and j
- different dimensions (same aspect is required)
- different compression (tolerance is required in case of quality loss like jpeg artifacts) - you can accept a 99% equality to be the same image and 50% to be a different one.

Cheers..!!  ;)

Answer (score -1):

Why convert in base64 or compare every pixel if there's hash comparison? 
Do something like this:

```
byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
byte[] hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(fileData);
```

And simply compare the hashes.

You'll need `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` for that.

Comment: Identical images may have differences in how they are encoded (progressive or interlaced, for example, or different levels of error-correction code), so needn't be bit-identical.  Also, when there's a match, you'd still have to also compare the actual data as well, given that hash collisions are possible.

Comment: First of all, if that would be the case base64 and pixel comparison wouldn't work either. Second, OP hasn't mentioned anything in that regard. If the plan is to compare slightly different images you could use the library OpenCV and a method like SIFT or SURF

Comment: That makes no sense - there's no base-64 in the code that I can see, and I've just explained where pixel comparison shows identical content from different image files.

Comment: Second most upvoted answer is suggesting base64 string comparison. Nice that you take the time to check before you randomly downvote others answers.

Comment: You have no idea which answers I have voted on (up or down), nor whether any of those votes were random, so please stop hurling accusations.